# updating JLabel with multithreading every second

Tags: java, multithreading

i try to make thread count down and i want to update this count in my Jlabel but it always show empty label this is my code

```
    public static String all;
private static int sec = 59, hour = 7, min = 59;
@Override
public void run() {
    while (sec > 0) {
        System.out.format("%02d:" + "%02d:" + "%02d\n", hour, min, sec);
        try {
            sec--;
            Thread.sleep(1000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        if (sec == 0) {
            if (min == 0) {
                if (hour == 0) {
                    break;
                }
                hour--;
                min = 59;
            }
            min--;
            sec = 59;
        }
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(String.valueOf(hour))
                .append(":")
                .append(String.valueOf(min))
                .append(":")
                .append(String.valueOf(sec));
        all = builder.toString();
        tesmy.myNum(all); //this method send the for my gui the time every second
    }
}
 }
```

i sure that he send time correct but i dont know how to update my label every second 
i play this class in thread 
this is my Jlabel

```
JLabel jLabel = new JLabel();
    jLabel.setBounds(175, 170, 70, 20);
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            jLabel.setText(myString);
        }
    });

    add(jLabel);
```

Comment: What is `tesmy.myNum(String)`?

Comment: send the time to my Jlabel

Comment: That seems to be a critical function that's probably part of the issue... You should edit your question to include its code

Comment: Can you tell me why are you creating thread in your myNum() method? Rather than creating thread can you try "jLabel.setText(myString);" only?

Comment: no i can if i do that no thinge will run except this code this is a part of my code and i i need to count down 8 hours and put is count in label while every thing in app work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to use Thread?

Java provides Swing Timer to update text of a label every second.

See this tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Hope this helps :)